# При выполнении деструктора краш программы

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть у меня код

Abiturient.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Object{
    string object;
    unsigned int rating;
};

class Abiturient{
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    unsigned int count_objects;
    Object* objects;
public:
    Abiturient();
    ~Abiturient();

    void input();

    friend class List;
};

class List{
private:
    Abiturient* list;
    unsigned int size;
public:
    List(unsigned int);
    ~List();

};
```

Abiturient.cpp

```
#include "Abiturient.h"


Abiturient::Abiturient(){
    name = string();
    surname = string();
}

Abiturient::~Abiturient(){
    delete[] objects;
}

void Abiturient::input(){
    cout << "Ввод данных абитуриента" << endl;
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Введите фамилию: ";
    cin >> surname;
    cout << "Введите кол-во предметов: ";
    cin >> count_objects;

    objects = new Object[count_objects];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count_objects; i++){
        cout << "Введите название " << i + 1 << "-его предмета: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,objects[i].object);
        cout << "Введите бал: ";
        cin >> objects[i].rating;
    }
}

List::List(unsigned int size){
    this->size = size;
    list = new Abiturient[this->size];
}

List::~List(){
    delete[] list;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Abiturient.h"

int main(){

        setlocale(LC_ALL,"Ukrainian");
    
        unsigned int size;
        cout << "Введите кол-во абитуриентов: ";
        cin >> size;
    
        List lst(size);
    
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Понимаю что скорее всего проблема в деструкторе и динамической памяти,но не могу разобратся что именно сделал не так,прошу помощи

Comment: Я так понимаю, программа падает в этом деструкторе: ```Abiturient::~Abiturient()```? А Вы уверены, к моменту вызова ```delete[]``` в том, что ```new``` для ```objects``` вызывался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как абсолютно правильно написал Юрий Козлов, у вас `new` для `objects` вызывается в `Abiturient::input()`. А её вы в коде не вызываете. Поэтому в деструкторе `~Abiturient()` вызывается `delete[]` для неинициализированного указателя `Object* objects;`.
Как быстрый вариант решения - обнулите указатель в конструкторе. Функция `delete[]` для нулевого указателя не делает ничего.

```
Abiturient::Abiturient(): objects(nullptr) {}

Abiturient::~Abiturient(){
    delete[] objects;
}
```

Кроме того, поскольку вы в деструкторе управляете ресурсом, чтобы избежать в дальнейшем множества ошибок, связанным с разделением владения ресурсом, вам необходимо следовать [правило Пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)). С существующим кодом у вас опять будут ошибки по доступу к памяти после любого копирования объекта `Abiturient`.
Но вообще, лучше следовать идиоме управления ресурсами RAII (resource aquitization is initialization) - в конструкторе создавать ресурс (захватывать), в деструкторе - освобождать. Для этого в С++ сделали классы умных указателей `unique_ptr<>`.

```
class Abiturient{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> objects{};
```

А ещё лучше, если вы вместо ручной работы с памятью, будете пользоваться контейнерами STL

```
class Abiturient{
private:
    std::vector<Object> objects;
```